# open a page to new window/tab from iframe

Tags: asp.net

I have a page with an iFrame on it.
On the page in the frame I have a button.

What I want is that if the user clicks on the button, another page is opened in it's own new window or tab. This functionality is to show the user a print friendly page.

How can I do this?

This is how I now try it:

```
Dim sb2 As New StringBuilder
sb2.Append("window.open('")
sb2.Append(sb.ToString)
sb2.Append("','NewPFWindow','menubar=1,toolbar=1,scrollbars=1,resizable=1,sandbox=""allow-same-origin allow-forms""')")

ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Me.GetType, "si2", sb2.ToString, True)
```

sb holds the page like "mypage.aspx"

Another option is to resize the iFrame so the whole page will fit. Is that possible from code-behind?

rg.
Eric

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found it.

Apparently Chrome uses an undocumented feature.

The frame that is trying to put the new page in it's own window or tab, needs an extra option in the sandbox property called "Allow-popup'.

This is not documented on the [w3schools.com](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_iframe_sandbox.asp) website.

So by adding this to the sandbox property, you allow the browser to create new window/tab.

Comment: [Please, don't link to or use w3schools. It's a shitty reference full of incorrect information that sometimes even leads to security holes.](http://w3fools.com)

Comment: Since I didn't want to completely rewrite your question and answer and this issue applies to HTML in general and not ASP.net; I created a new Q&A here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21236617/900747   @ThiefMaster, +1, definitely. Although I still use them to double-check syntax for various new HTML5 features since they come up top at Google every time.

Answer (score 0):

Just provide a `target` that has not been named on your site yet, most people will use `_blank` for that

I.e.

```
<a href="desiredLocationUrl...." target="_blank"> link text </a>
```

or if you want to tie that to another click-event somewhere else:

```
window.open('desiredLocationUrl....', "_blank");
```

Btw. it does not matter if that link is inside an iframe ;)

Comment: @Eric your code seems to be what would be needed here, what happens if you click the button now? Anything? Nothing? I think it should actually already be the correct code, maybe try switching `'NewPFWindow'` with `'_blank'`

Comment: Hi, When I click on the button, nothing happens. I think the popup blocker is blocking it. And since the browser doesn't show the warning and let you add the website to the list of sites allowed to use popups. Maybe that is because I watch the site in VS in debug mode.

Comment: @Eric If it is blocked by popup blocker YOU SHOULD actually get a notification about that, try it out in a different browser or switch off your popup blocker to ensure that. Fortunately (But unfortunately for you) you cannot guarantee that popups will be opened on the client side, because as you stated there are popup blockers that override that behavior.

Comment: I switched off the popup blocker, but still no result. I checked the code, it is executed, so why no new window?