# Sandboxed iFrame with `target="_blank"` doesn't open new tab or window

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, sandbox

I just created an iFrame with the `sandbox` attribute. Whenever I try to open a link with `target="_blank"` or `target="_top"` or when I try to use `window.open()` nothing happens.

Here's my code:

```
<iframe src="http://www.google.com/"
  sandbox="allow-top-navigation allow-same-origin allow-forms allow-scripts">

    Apparently your browser doesn't support iFrames!

</iframe>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Apparently Chrome allows an undocumented sandbox property called `allow-popups` to be set. The property is also supported in Firefox and is a Candidate Recommendation on [W3C](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#attr-iframe-sandbox-allow-popups).

`allow-popups` lets the sandboxed frame open links in new windows or tabs and, it appears, when the frame tries to open a link with `target="_top"` the browser will open the URL in a new tab or window.

Comment: `allow-popups` _is_ documented/specified, see http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/browsers.html#sandboxing

Comment: I don't see it mentioned there. Maybe I'm misunderstanding it, they're hard to read.

Comment: I guess it's the "sandboxed auxiliary navigation browsing context flag". I'll edit my answer.

Comment: Look at the list a little bit further down on how a user agent has to parse the sandboxing flag, in step #3 there it says, _“Add the following flags to output: […] The sandboxed auxiliary navigation browsing context flag, unless tokens contains the `allow-popups` keyword.”_

Comment: Chrome also supports ["allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox"](https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/allow-popups-to-escape-sandbox/)